# Getting Error "Unable to sign input, invalid stack size (possibly missing key)"

Tags: transactions, wallet, private-key, signature

I have created a key from using [coinstring](http://cryptocoinjs.com/modules/currency/coinstring/), and then imported it into my wallet. Then I ran:

```
bitcoin-cli signrawtransactionwithkey "$rawtxhex" "[\"$mykey$\"]"
```

But it results in:

```
Unable to sign input, invalid stack size (possibly missing key)
```

Any ideas? My `mykey` is not actually a variable, I am hardcoding it in my specific case so I know it is present.

Comment: What type of address did you make from the private key?

Comment: @AndrewChow what do you mean? I just pasted the private key directly in that command.

Comment: Before you can sign a transaction with a private key, you need to send Bitcoin to an address that is controlled by that private key. What type of address did you send to? P2PKH? Segwit? Something else?

Comment: @AndrewChow can you please direct me to some documentation, I am not sure what you're talking about. How can I send bitcoin to an address if creating a transaction requires signing something with the key in the first place?

Comment: You don't need to sign anything with the key first to send to an address controlled by it. You need to sign the transaction when you are trying to SPEND those coins. Receiving coins on an address does not require the private key at all except to produce the address in the first place.

Comment: Can you post what `$rawtxhex` is? How did you create it?